# Can I update/set state properties by using map to call a function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, state

New to ReactJS.

I'm attempting to build a little component that moves some components around a container. The idea is that the user clicks on a button and the divs position changes.

I've tried to use `Object.keys` and `Object.entries` neither of them worked. I tried to create an array out of `this.state` so that I could just do `array.map()` but it did not work.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleShuffle = this.handleShuffle.bind(this);

    this.state = {
        redLeft: 0,
        redTop: 0,
        blueLeft: 0,
        blueTop: 70
    }
}

getRandomNumber (min, max) {
    return min + (Math.floor(Math.random() * (max-min)))
}

handleShuffle() {
    const min = 0;
    const max = 230;

this.setState({
    redLeft: this.getRandomNumber(min, max),
    redTop: this.getRandomNumber(min, max),
    blueLeft: this.getRandomNumber(min, max),
    blueTop: this.getRandomNumber(min, max),
});
}
```

The code above is as far as I got, it works but surely there is a way to loop over the different properties in `this.state` and call the function for each item?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate through object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not sure why `Object.keys` doesn't work for you but it does actually work. Here, I loop over the keys of `this.state` and set the state for that key.

```js
class Foo extends React.Component {
     constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        
        this.state = {
            redLeft: 0,
            redTop: 0,
            blueLeft: 0,
            blueTop: 70
        }
    }
    
    componentDidMount () {
       this.handleShuffle()
    }
  
    getRandomNumber (min, max) {
        return min + (Math.floor(Math.random() * (max-min)))
    }
  
    handleShuffle() {
        const min = 0;
        const max = 230;
        
        Object.keys(this.state).map(k => {
           this.setState({ 
             [k]: this.getRandomNumber(min, max)
           })
        })
    }
    
    render () {
      return JSON.stringify(this.state)
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Foo />, document.getElementById('foo'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo"></div>
```

Comment: I know it's not the most elegant solution but please explain the down vote.

Answer (score 0):

You could use reduce if your state only ever includes keys you want to apply the random number to:

```
this.setState((prevState) => (Object
  .keys({...prevState})
  .reduce((newState, next) => {
    newState[next] = this.getRandomNumber(min, max);
    return newState;
}, {})));
```